# Declaring a static array of bytes in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I can declare a static byte array in VBA like this, but it appears that the elements are not of type byte.

```
Dim A As Variant
A = Array(&H9F, &H2C, &H3B, &HFF, &H84)
```

I can solve this by copying the content to a second array, but that doesn't look very efficient to me.

```
Dim A As Variant
A = Array(&H9F, &H2C, &H3B, &HFF, &H84)
Dim N As Long: N = UBound(A)
Dim B() As Byte
ReDim B(N)
For X = 0 To N
    B(X) = A(X)
Next
```

So my question is: is there a better or more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, probably not the solution you were looking for, but you can convert a string directly to a byte array..

So, for your example, something (crazy) like this will work..

```
Dim bResult() As Byte
bResult = StrConv(Join(Array(Chr(&H9F), Chr(&H2C), Chr(&H3B), Chr(&HFF), Chr(&H84)), vbNullString), vbFromUnicode)
```

A second method would be to update the elements in the original array.
it still requires a loop, but the entries will then by Bytes

```
Dim i As Long
Dim vValues As Variant: vValues = Array(&H9F, &H2C, &H3B, &HFF, &H84)
For i = LBound(vValues) To UBound(vValues)
    vValues(i) = CByte(vValues(i))
Next i
```

Finally you could just do this:

```
Dim vValues As Variant 
vValues = Array(CByte(&H9F), CByte(&H2C), CByte(&H3B), CByte(&HFF), CByte(&H84))
```

Comment: I was aware of the fact that you can assign a string directly to a byte array. Only I would have used a for loop to join the elements,, which I wanted to avoid. Your solution is a bit cleaner, but like you said, still not the one I was looking for.

Comment: yeah, it's probably the only solution without using a loop sadly. Ive added a second method. updating the type of each array element is slightly better than using a second array it think.